# Error occurred during a cryptographic operation on Website using Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory to sign in on my website.

First time we login is fine but after some time when we do a refresh we get error message :

Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.]
   System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input) +175
  Web.Models.ADALTokenCache..ctor(String signedInUserId) in 
  Web\Models\AdalTokenCache.cs:30

I searched and found some solutions but none seems to work :

BeforeAccessNotification :

```
       try
        {
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
        }
        catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException cge)
        {
            db.UserTokenCaches.Remove(Cache);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

AfterAccessNotification :

```
            if (Cache == null)
            {
                Cache = new UserTokenCache
                {
                    webUserUniqueId = userId,
                    cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), 
                    "ADALCache"),
                    LastWrite = DateTime.Now
                };
            }

            //Cache.cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), 
             "ADALCache");
            //Cache.LastWrite = DateTime.Now;

            // update the DB and the lastwrite 
            db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? 
            EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            this.HasStateChanged = false;
```

Comment: Can you share the details of what token cache implementation you are using?

Comment: I have added the Azure Active Directory from the VS2017 Wizard. It added codes in the Startup.cs and Startup.Auth.cs. It uses the UserTokenCache table to insert the token.

Comment: Seems like the error might be coming from the constructor of your token cache class, can you post that too?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
    {
        // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
        userId = signedInUserId;
        this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
        // look up the entry in the database
        Cache = db.UserTokenCaches.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
        // place the entry in memory
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
    }
```